# Can Javascript be written in a html href tag?

Tags: javascript, security, html-agility-pack, whitelist

I am trying to figure out all the ways javascript can be written. I am making a white list of acceptable tags however the attributes are getting me.

In my rich html editor I allow stuff like links.

```
<a href="">Hi </a>
```

Now I am using html agility pack to get rid of attributes I won't support and html tags for that matter.

However I am still unclear if a person could do something like this

```
<a href="<script>alert('hi')</script>">Bad </a>
```

So I am not sure if I have to start looking at the inner text of all attributes that I support and html encode them? Or if what.

I am also not sure how to prevent a html link that goes to some page and launches some javascript on load.

I am not sure if a white list can stop that one.

Comment: What you show shouldn't work, but `href="javascript:alert('Hello!');"` is a perfectly acceptable way of embedding Javascript.

Comment: Ya I really have no clue where java script be put in I just knew it could be put in there. So where else can it be put in what should I be watching for?

Comment: Like what attributes can these things go in? Can it go in the "id" attribute or name attribute...etc. I have no clue where to find this information out.

Comment: @Pekka: More than acceptable - it's common.

Comment: @George, Common true, but it's not accepted nowadays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert('hi');">Bad</a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hi');">Bad</a>
```

Comment: Ah! Please people - stop putting "#" as the href for links that execute JavaScript. Use "javascript:void(0)" instead. That way the page doesn't scroll to the top when the link is clicked.

Comment: @George: Care to explain why?

Comment: @George - I removed it, though if that's your biggest issue, you can add a "return false" at the end of the onclick attribute.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to write an XSS validator for user-entered HTML for production, I highly recommend you use an existing library. Even with the whitelist approach you are taking, there are many, many possible attribute values that can result in XSS. Search for "javascript:" in the [XSS Cheat Sheet](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) to see all sorts of places javascript: uris can turn up. Here is an incomplete list:

```
<IMG SRC="javascript:alert('XSS');">
<INPUT TYPE="IMAGE" SRC="javascript:alert('XSS');">
<BODY BACKGROUND="javascript:alert('XSS')">
<IMG LOWSRC="javascript:alert('XSS')">
```

There are also ways to inject external script urls, like this:

```
<XSS STYLE="behavior: url(xss.htc);">
```

If you're writing this for your own education, then the XSS Cheat Sheet has some really great fodder for unit tests.

Comment: Naw I am not trying to use an XSS validator...I would use the one that comes with asp.net mvc. I am trying to make a whitelist.

Comment: Oh good :)  But I think the cheat sheet still answers your question about all the ways JavaScript can be written.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure how to handle a couple of these cases. UTF-8 Unicode encoding one, hex encoding, jav ascript , jav&#x09;ascript. Httml agility pack helps me with the <script> ones but I don'tthink these ones.

Comment: Can the word javascript in these tags have any number of spaces(ie can you have j space a space v space a....

Comment: No spaces in "javascript" -- but it can be any case, and have spaces (and looks like some other special chars) before and after "javascript".

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){
    alert('hello');
})()">Hello</a>
```

if you want to get really crazy

**Edit:**
I like this even better

```
<a onclick="alert(eval({Crazy:function(){alert('Hello');return 'World';}}).Crazy());">
    Crazy
</a>
```

Comment: you could put whole classes in there

Comment: You could even in theory import an external javascript file and access pretty much anything on the page and send it anywhere on the internet.

Comment: So how do you stop this with a whitelist( I am using html agility pack) without just not allowing links?

Comment: use regex to parse the href attribute and only allow fully qualified links.  Something like

    ^http(s)?://(www\.)?(\w+\.)?(\w+)\.(com)$

I know that's not completely right but I just wrote it on the fly

Comment: Ya that's what I actually did I used regex but apparently I still have to worry about UTF-8 Unicode encoding one, hex encoding, jav ascript , jav&#x09;ascript. So I am not sure how to deal with them.